# How can I export a class with multiple static methods

Tags: node.js, class, export

I am trying to export this class in node.js:

```
export class className {
  static method1(param1) {
    // do something
  }

  static method2(param1, param2) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But it's getting me the following errors in terminal:

> complete_path.....\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\classCallCheck.js:1 [2] (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
>   export default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { [2]
>   ^^^^^^ [2] [2] SyntaxError: Unexpected token export [2]     at new
>   Script (vm.js:83:7) [2]     at createScript (vm.js:267:10) [2]     at
>   Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10) [2]     at Module._compile
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28) [2]     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
>   [2]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32) [2]
>   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12) [2]     at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3) [2]
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17) [2]     at
>   require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) [2] [nodemon] app
>   crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 3):

The `export` keyword is not supported by Node.js yet. You have to use the `exports` or `module.exports` ones.

In your case you should use the `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = class className {
  static method1(param1) {
    // do something
  }

  static method2(param1, param2) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

For more information about the difference between the `exports` and `module.exports` I suggest you this [post](https://blog.tableflip.io/the-difference-between-module-exports-and-exports/).

Answer (score 2):

Use `module.exports` and not `export`

```
module.exports = class className {

 static method1(param1) {
     // do something
 }


 static method2(param1, param2) {
     // do something
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mayur, but getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" now.

during 
import { className } from '../../folder/exportedClassFile';

Comment: @AlamgirKhan Pure node.js doesn’t use “import  ... from...”.  You should use “const ...= require(...)”

Comment: @BogdanSurai i tried with required also, but same issue. and for import i am using babel so instead of class using `module.exports ={ and then functions ...` working just fine even if i use `import * as someObj from '../../folder/thatFileName';` .... but not sure why we can't export classes i tried @Mayur @Yannick Loriot method also!

Comment: I don't think you can use `import { className }`. Try `import className from classFile`. Or, `module.exports = {className}`. Then, `import {className} from classFile`